# discord.js Cannot read property 'get' of undefined (client.channels.get())

Tags: javascript, typeerror, discord.js

I've been trying to get a channel object by ID and put it into a database under the 'channel' key.
However it's telling me that client.channels is undefined!

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'channel',
    description: 'Pong!',
    execute(client) {
        const db = require('../databases.js');
        const channel = client.channels.get('some channnel id');
        db.config.set('channel', channel);
    },
};
```

The relevant part of index.js:

```
const
    fs = require('fs'), //loads native filesystem module
    Discord = require('discord.js'), //loads discord.js
    Enmap = require('enmap'), //loads enmap
    client = new Discord.Client(), //creates new client
    db = require('./databases.js'); //initializes all databases
require('colors'); //loads colors package
```

...command handling...

```
if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName);
    try {
        command.execute(message, args, client, member, Enmap);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(('[main] ' + error).red);
        message.channel.send('This command has run into an error.');
    }
```

Comment: Where are you getting `client` from? Show us that part of the code.

Comment: edited to add that.

Comment: and what part calls `execute(client)` function that you are exporting?

Comment: its the try...catch statement after handling all the commands in a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly according to your comments.

`command.execute(message, args, client, member, Enmap);` is calling this function:

```js
execute(client) {
    const db = require('../databases.js');
    const channel = client.channels.get('some channnel id');
    db.config.set('channel', channel);
},
```

This `execute` function expects one param as `client` yet above you are passing 5 parameters and `client` being the third one.

Something doesn't add up. You should change the `execute` function to either accept 5 params or only pass `client` to it.

If I misunderstood, I apologise. Let me know and I can edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you! i didn't know this was how `execute` works. i made one-two adjustments and now it works.

Comment: Great, glad I could help :)